# How to rename the plugin PHP file without affecting existent users?

Tags: plugin-development

A plugin of mine has main PHP file named "init.php", now I want to follow best practice and rename it to "plugin-name.php"

As users are used to upgrade the plugin by overwriting the old folder with update, so there will be

```
init.php
plugin-name.php
```

both exist in the plugin folder after upgrade, which results in a PHP fatal error, saying a class not found, whatever, deleting "init.php" and all clear.

Though I can tell users how to fix it when they contact me, but it isn't a good solution to throw the error on users, is there a way to remove or ignore legacy main plugin file in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the plugin version delete the file `init.php` on upgrading from the plugin folder. For this purpose you can use the [Filesystem API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API), especially the [`delete()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_filesystem_direct/delete/) - here exemplary linked to the `WP_Filesystem_Direct` class.

Comment: I have figured it out a while ago too, but what I use is php method `unlink(__FILE__)`, tested ok on my host server though, is there any benefits using `delete()`?

Comment: @Edward It has an additional security check, but aside from that does use `unlink()` too. So pretty much no benefits. One point could be consistency with using WordPress API functions, hasn't to do with functionality though.